# Makefile: Targets for Crosscombinations

Tags: makefile, target

I have 2 types of files. Scripts and datasets. I want to write a makefile to run each script with each dataset. 
My idea was to create a target for each output, where the target has a name containing the script and the model name. These targets would match a "target-pattern"-rule (of type: some_folder/%.eval). Now the "target-pattern"-rule would need to figure out from its name which files are needed. But this seems to be a hard job.

Is there a better, more elegant way?

Example:

> Files: ScriptA, ScriptB, InputA, InputB
>
> Targets/Outputfiles: InputA_ScriptA, InputA_ScriptB, InputB_ScriptA, InputB_ScriptB

```
# generate all combinations
RT_HW = $(foreach script,$(RT_SCRIPT_HW),$(foreach input, $(RT_INPUTS), $(input)_$(script)))

$(SANDBOX)%.eval: <requires Script X and input X>
```

Comment: Is your example what you *have*, or what you *want?*

Comment: The example is what I want. I can generate the names of the target. That's no problem. But the dependency goes the other way and are hard to describe.

Comment: This question sounds familiar. If I can find the prior, I'll add a link and mark this Question as a duplicate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've run into one of the major shortcomings of Make: it isn't very good with wildcards.

You can get the effect you want by generating rules with [eval](http://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function), either by iterating over both variables:

```
define template
$(1)_$(2).eval: $(1) $(2)
    @echo target is $$@
    @echo running $(2) on $(1)
endef

$(foreach script,$(RT_SCRIPT_HW),$(foreach input, $(RT_INPUTS), $(eval $(call template,$(input),$(script)))))
```

or by generating pattern rules, iterating over only one, such as the input:

```
define template
$(1)_%.eval: $(1) %
    @echo target is $$@
    @echo running $$* on $(1)
endef

$(foreach input, $(RT_INPUTS), $(eval $(call template,$(input))))
```