# Makefile : create rules from a list of patterns

Tags: makefile

In my directory, I have many files named 
A.xxx A01.xxx A02.xxx A03.xxx
B.xxx B01.xxx

Z......

I would like to create rules like

```
A.yyy : A.xxx
      command type 1

A01.yyy : A01.xxx A.xxx
      command type 2

B.yyy : B.xxx
      command type 1
B01.yyy : B01.xxx B.xxx
      command type 2

Z01.yyy: Z01.xxx
      command type 3
```

Can someone give me an hint ?

I tried something like this (it seems ok for command 1 an 3, but in command 2 , I don't see how to put the second perequisit)

```
list:= A B 
source=$(wildcard *.xxx)
compi:=$(patsubst %.xxx, %.yyy, $(source))
list_pattern=$(addsuffix %, $(list))
list_yyy=$(addsuffix .yyy, $(list))
list_nb_yyy=$(filter $(list_pattern), $(compi))

%.yyy:%xxx
      @echo $@ - $+ -  command 3

all: $(compi)

.SECONDEXPANSION:
$(list_yyy):  $$(patsubst %.yyy, %.xxx, $$@)
     @echo $@ - $+ - command 1
$(list_nb_yyy):  $$(patsubst %.yyy, %.xxx, $$@)
     @echp $@ - $+ - command 2
```

Comment: Your question is unclear. How do you want it to build `A02.yyy`? Is there a `B05.xxx`?

Comment: I try to symplify my problem. For example
A02.yyy : A02.xxx A.xxx ; cat $+ > $@

I can have hundreds of files of type or A....xxx B....xxx and  C....xxx D....xxx too, so I need to have a list with all prefixes A B C D  because i don't want to dot all by hand

Comment: Is there a way to extract the string A out of a string A...., when A is part of a list ?

Comment: You can find the answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39956772/makefile-targets-for-crosscombinations/39965530#39965530), but it involves some advanced Make techniques.

Answer (score 3):

Two important parts of the documentation that you should read include:

- [8.9 The eval Function](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Eval-Function)

> The eval function is very special: it allows you to define new makefile constructs that are not constant; which are the result of evaluating other variables and functions. The argument to the eval function is expanded, then the results of that expansion are parsed as makefile syntax. The expanded results can define new make variables, targets, implicit or explicit rules, etc.

- [10.5.4 How Patterns Match](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/make.html#Pattern-Match), particularly the shortest stem rule:

> It is possible that more than one pattern rule will meet these criteria. In that case, make will choose the rule with the shortest stem (that is, the pattern that matches most specifically). If more than one pattern rule has the shortest stem, make will choose the first one found in the makefile.

The shortest stem rule will make it difficult to have 3 different pattern rules for `A.yyy`, `A01.yyy` and `Z01.yyy` respectively. However, with the eval function you can use the information available in the `list` variable to generate non-pattern rules for `A.yyy` and `B.yyy`, and the correct pattern rules for the other targets (assuming that the decision is made on the prefix of the name):

```
list:= A B
source=$(wildcard *.xxx)
compi:=$(patsubst %.xxx, %.yyy, $(source))

all: $(compi)

define LIST_RULE
$(1).yyy: $(1).xxx
    @echo $$@ - $$+ - command 1
$(1)%.yyy: $(1)%.xxx $(1).xxx
    @echo $$@ - $$+ - command 2
endef
$(foreach l,$(list),$(eval $(call LIST_RULE,$(l))))

%.yyy: %.xxx
    @echo $@ - $+ -  command 3
```

Note that the fallback solution (`command 3`) won't be selected for `A01.yyy` and `B01.yyy` because the pattern rule in the `LIST_RULE` template leads to a shorter stem (`01` instead of `A01` or `B01`)

Comment: thx very much, I'll try this. As new user for makefiles, it seems to be a liitle hard : nice challenge !!